# Как лучше реализовать всплывающие подсказки?

Tags: unity3d

Например, когда игрок подходит к лежащему на земле оружию он видит всплывающую подсказку: "*Нажмите E, чтобы подобрать*".
Я вот думаю, либо на каждом оружие будет объект с текстом который будет включаться по вхождению в триггер, либо Instantiate текст над оружием. Может ещё другие варианты есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема приведенных Вами методов в том, что Вам каждый раз нужно будет показывать текст относительно камеры персонажа, то есть вычислять угол и положение. Я думаю удобнее будет сделать это через [OnGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html).

Примерно так:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (something)//Условие наведение камеры на оружие, или пересечение коллайдера области подбора оружия
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 300, 50), ("Press E to pick up item!"));
    }
}
```

В данном примере подсказка отображается по центру экрана и с дефолтными настройками текста.
У этого метода 5 перегрузок, там можно настроить стиль текста и контейнера отображения.

Comment: Текст будет разный для каждого оружия, + я хочу чтобы текст спавнился в 2Д мире над предметом

Comment: И вы хотите создать кучу текстовых элементов и вносить их под разные префабы? Такой подход грозит Вам проблемами при большом количестве объектов и при последующей доработке и поддержке игры. Правильнее будет создать список подсказок и передавать содержимое определенного элемента списка в зависимости от названия предмета или его тэга. В этом случае Вам не придётся хранить кучу текстовых элементов.

Comment: Немного не то, но тоже сойдёт для реализации подобной механики.